# How to find pearson correlation between rows in two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have a dataframe that I split into two dataframes of the same amount of columns and rows (df1 and df2). I want to write a function that will go through each row and feed their values into the scipy.stats.pearsonr() function. How would I do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for index, row in d1.iterrows():
    print(scipy.stats.pearsonr(df1.loc[index], df2.loc[index]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the function, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [0,2,3,4,5],
        'B': [2,3,4,5,6],
        'C': [5,6,7,8,9],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [2,1,3,4,5],
        'B': [3,2,4,5,6],
        'C': [7,7,7,3,3],
    }
)


def pandas_pearsonr(df1, df2):
    assert len(df1)==len(df2)
    coefs = []
    for i in range(0, len(df1)):
        coefs.append(pearsonr(df1.iloc[i].values, df2.iloc[i].values))
    print(coefs)
    return pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index, data=coefs, columns=['coef', 'p-value'])

pandas_pearsonr(df1, df2)
```

Output looks like this:

```
    coef    p-value
0   0.976221    0.139109
1   0.996271    0.054996
2   1.000000    0.000000
3   -0.720577   0.487754
4   -0.838628   0.366717
```

But I think, it can be more pythonic. And maybe you can use `pandas.DataFrame.corr`